# Hide Android SoftKeyboard with CommunityToolkit

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit

I'm trying to make a Maui app to use in a PDA on my work. To make it more usable I need to hide the softkeyboard that popup when the focus go in any Entry or any searchbar.
Following many question, I have found a that CommunityToolkit have Method to  [hide the software keyboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/extensions/keyboard-extensions)

I was able to implement the a button with the command in the viewmodel to hide the keyboard and it work great.

```
        [RelayCommand]
    async Task OnHideKeyboard(ITextInput view, CancellationToken token)
    {
        try
        {
            await view.HideKeyboardAsync(token);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            OperationResult = e.Message;
        }
    }
```

But If I add in the code behind the suggested code to hide it for example on the load event:

```
#if ANDROID
    await CodeEntry.HideKeyboardAsync(CancellationToken.None);
#endif
```

Nothing happen. It doesn't give any error, simply the keyboard doesn't hide.

Any suggestion why?

@Jianwei Sun - MSFT I have copied your solution (changing the name of the entry) but give 2 errors.

Adding: (NuovoEan is the name of the Entry)

```
    protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
{
    base.OnHandlerChanged();
    ((AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.AppCompatEditText)NuovoEan.Handler.PlatformView).InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.Null;
}
```

An added the using Statement `using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration;`
Give error "AndroidX not found" and "Android Not contain a definition for 'Text'"

But the main question still is:
Why the Community Toolkit Method doesn't work?

Comment: *" but give 2 errors"* What's the errors? Please show them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to achieve it:

page.xaml:

```xml
    ....
    <Entry x:Name="MyEntry"/>
    ....
```

page.xaml.cs:

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public MainPage() 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
    {
        base.OnHandlerChanged();

#if ANDROID
        ((AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.AppCompatEditText)MyEntry.Handler.PlatformView)
        .InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.Null;

#endif
    }
}
```